# Cognos Mobile - How to avoid Prompt page

Tags: mobile, report, prompt, cognos

I have a report with 3 value prompt. When I open the report on the desktop, all the prompt appear in the report. But when I open the report from an iPad I don't have the prompts in the report. Instead of that, I have a prompt page which appears.

But in the aim to refresh the report more efficiently, I need to keep this value prompt inside the report with Cognos Mobile and not have a prompt page.

Are there any changes to do in the value prompt properties or anything else ? Or is it simply impossible ?
Does anyboday have any idea ?

Comment: I haven't tried cognos mobile. Can you try what happens if you place your prompts both in prompt page and report page? Make sure that you use the same parameters for the second set of prompts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created a prompt page with the same parameters which are in the report. Unfortunately there is the same issue with the report. Only the prompt page is different because it is not the default prompt page but a customize. So I can't change the parameters from the report page.

Comment: I founded a little trick. Instead of using the report pages I put the objects (table, chart) directly in a prompt page with the parameters. I duplicate this prompt page. On the first prompt page I keep the button "Next" and in the second the button "Previous". With this trick I can switch between the 2 pages. The interest of duplicating the prompt page is, when I change paramater value with the value prompt, the changes are saved and to view the data corresponding to this new paramaters I open the other prompt page with the "Next" or "Previous" button.

Comment: Thus we can modify the parameters and view the corresponding data by switching prompt pages. I know this is not very fine but actually it is the only one solution that I founded to resolve the this issue for Cognos Mobile.